# Dynamically Duplicate HTML DIV with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML, Java, AJAX, and Heavy Javascript to pull records out of a database and display them dynamically on a page based on the users search parameters. Pretty basic concept...My question isn't necessarily a "How do I make this work?" type question because the way i've got everything set up, it works just fine. I do however believe there must be a slightly cleaner approach that would create more maintainable code. My main goal is to be able to completely separate the design aspects of my web page from the Javascript so that a web designer would not have to touch the Javascript at all in order to make changes to the appearance of the data presented. Let me begin by showing you how I currently have things set up.

On the HTML page, I am simply using a container DIV as a placeholder so I have somewhere to insert the dynamically created DIVs from Javascript. Otherwise, that container DIV is completely empty according to the HTML.

Now, diving into the Javascript. When I pull records from the database, I use a for loop to build a DIV containing all the data I wish to display. Then using the for loop I simply append the DIV into the HTML container DIV for each record:

```
function getPhoneNumbers() {
    var length = contact.phone.length;

    if(length > 0) {
        //Remove any previous numbers.
        var container = document.getElementById('popupPhoneNumbers');
        clearAllChildNodes(container);

        for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
            container.appendChild(new phoneNumberRow(i, contact.phone[i]));
        }
    }
}

function phoneNumberRow(id, phoneNumber) {
var rowDiv = document.createElement('div');
rowDiv.id = 'popup-phone-number-' + id;
rowDiv.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'toggleEditPhone(' + id + ');');
rowDiv.setAttribute('onmouseout', 'toggleEditPhone(' + id + ');');

//Set primary class.
var primaryClass = 'primary-off';

if(phoneNumber.isPrimary) {
    primaryClass = 'primary-on';
}

//Primary button display
var primaryContainer = document.createElement('div');
primaryContainer.id = rowDiv.id + '-primary';
primaryContainer.setAttribute('class', primaryClass);
primaryContainer.style.display = 'inline';
var primaryButton = document.createElement('a');
primaryButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'PhoneUtility.setPrimary(' + id + ');');
primaryButton.innerHTML = 'P';
primaryContainer.appendChild(primaryButton);

//Phone number display
var phoneNumberRow = document.createElement('div');
phoneNumberRow.style.display = 'inline';
phoneNumberRow.innerHTML = phoneNumber.type + ' ' + phoneNumber.number;

//Edit buttons display
var editButtonsContainer = document.createElement('div');
editButtonsContainer.id = rowDiv.id + '-edit';
editButtonsContainer.style.display = 'none';
var editButton = document.createElement('a');
editButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'PhoneUtility.edit(' + id + ');');
editButton.innerHTML = 'Edit';
editButtonsContainer.appendChild(editButton);
var deleteButton = document.createElement('a');
deleteButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'PhoneUtility.remove(' + id + ');');
deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';
editButtonsContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);

//Append all children to container.
rowDiv.appendChild(primaryContainer);
rowDiv.appendChild(phoneNumberRow);
rowDiv.appendChild(editButtonsContainer);

return rowDiv;
}
```

As you can see I am doing a lot of HTML tag building in my Javascript, which works just fine, but if a designer with no Javascript experience had to manipulate this data, it would be a pretty miserable experience. Not to mention, i'd prefer for a designer to not even have to open up my JS files.

The approach i'd like to take, is to create all the container DIVs in the HTML and then use Javascript simply to insert the data into those elements, rather than have to create them. That way CSS styling can be applied to each DIV separately from the Javascript. But if I create one row of DIVs in the HTML, how do I go about duplicating the row for each record that I want to display? Is there some way to simply copy the pre-designed element into Javascript, fill in the data and repeat that row as necessary for each record I want to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using a javascript library here. If you were using jQuery you could simply use `clone` to make a deep copy of an element. [Clone Docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Otherwise you need to use the [cloneNode](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/cloneNode) method. It does a deep copy too.

How I would do this is create the element once in plain html/css, let your designer style it however he wants, then simply add a `.hidden` class to it. Give it an ID like `#rootElement` so you can find it easily later for cloning.

In your javascript, you can clone that element, fill it with data, and remove the `.hidden` class to make it visible to the user. The rest of your css rules will still apply.

Comment: Note that cloning the element will result in duplicate elements with the same id. You should avoid using id and instead use class names as recommended by the docs.